# Django Markdown Editor

Tags: django, wysiwyg, pagedown, django-markdown-deux

I would really like a clear straightforward example for implementing a text editor in Django that is like the proposed `pagedown` or `markdownx`.  I cannot get either of these solutions working in Django 2.0, and all the references I find including the documentation are around older versions of Django.

I just want one field in my models to be a text editor like this, that includes uploading images and the use of LaTeX/markdown.

I have followed the directions in the documentation for `markdownx`,specifically the steps where you set up a model: http://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/example.html.  After setting things up in the admin, I get an error about PIL.  I encounter errors when trying to upload images with the `ImageField` also.  I have pillow installed though...

Comment: what have you tried? where's your code?

Comment: edited to reflect markdownx attempt... @Lemayzeur

Comment: Do everything as described in their documentations. The extra things that you will need is to include 'mdx_math' in settings.MARKDOWNX_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS similar to what I have done here, `MARKDOWNX_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS = [
    'mdx_math',
    'markdown.extensions.sane_lists',
    'markdown.extensions.nl2br',
    'markdown.extensions.extra',
]` and `pip install mdx_math`. You will also need to include javascript files from Mathjax in your template.

Comment: @Inquilabi There is not a matching distribution for `mdx_math` when I try a pip install

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/mitya57/python-markdown-math/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2):

I just installed pagedown yesterday and is working perfectly.

Add pagedown to apps in your settings.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
     'pagedown',
]
```

Then just override the model's text field in the admin class.

```
from django.db import models
from pagedown.widgets import AdminPagedownWidget

from blog.models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'date_created', 'date_updated')
    formfield_overrides = {
    models.TextField: {'widget': AdminPagedownWidget},
    }

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

By the way, I used Django 2.1.1 and pagedown 1.0.6.

If this doesn't work, check to see if your pagedown version is current.

Comment: Okay, great, this works.  I'm disappointed though that here markdown doesn't render latex or support syntax highlighting.